# Replace PHP date output with pre-made images

Tags: php, css, image, date, replace

I am redesigning my personal starting page, which nobody else uses but me. I use PHP to show the current date. I display the date as day (fully written) - day (number) month (fully written) year (fully) - Week number.

The code I am using for this is:

```
<?php echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y | Week %V")?>
```

This worked perfectly for my old page, however for my new page I want the date to be shown in images, which I have already created in Photoshop. So the date, which is shown in PHP, should be replaced with the images.

Can someone please give me an example / code snippet on how I can do this? I tried searching for it on Google (for examples), but I couldn't find anything similar, nor do I possess the PHP knowledge to write something myself. I always try to learn, however I guess I am getting to old to learn new stuff.

Anyways, I have already created all the images which I need:

- the day fully written, for example: day-monday.png
- the day in number, for example: day-24.png
- the month fully written, for example: month-november.png
- the year fully writted, for example: year-2014.png
- the week number fully written, for example: week-48.png

Can someone please show me an example of how to get this working. I would really appreciate the effort. And I am sorry if I sound stupid and didn't want to offend anyone.

Thanks in advance already!

Comment: `$day_of_month = date('m'); echo "<img src=\"day-$day_of_month.jpg\" />";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<img src="day-<?php echo date('l');?>.png" />
<img src="day-<?php echo date('d');?>.png" />
<img src="month-<?php echo date('F');?>.png" />
<img src="year-<?php echo date('Y');?>.png" />
<img src="week-<?php echo date('W');?>.png" />
```

Just needs styling to how you want it laid out.

Comment: Damn... You guys make it always make it look so simple! I was already thinking that I would need a complete script for this, but the solution is really (actually) easy! Thank you so much for this. It works flawlessly. Thank you!!

Comment: No problem. You could have done some loops/arrays but whats the point when it only needs to be something super simple :)

Comment: Yeah, this is even understandable for a complete noob like myself. Once again; thank you very much for your helpful answer. :)